# How to download full daily historical data of MSCI AC Asia Index

Tags: equities, historical-data, index

I'm trying to download the daily historical data of the MSCI AC Asia Index. I've been testing different combinations of the following url: https://www.msci.com/eqb/esg/performance/110.0.all.html using the Asia index ID but can't figure out the correct link. The index ID is 2703.

I actually just need daily Asia index data starting from 1990 to present. Any leads for this would be great.

Comment: Do you need this just one time or on a recurring basis?

Answer (score 0):

All index data is available here:

https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-search

However, I don't believe the daily data extends to 1991 for this specific index.

Comment: Hi, thanks J-F! Unfortunately the available data from https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-search here is monthly. I'm trying to find a full download of the daily data